# API controller resolution returning undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js, passport.js

Essentially, my controller isn't returning the resolution of the promise properly.

```
  getUserByIdApi: async (req, res) => {
      const googleId = req;
      try {
        res.json(await fetchUserByIdFromDb(googleId))
        const user = await fetchUserByIdFromDb(googleId);

        res.send(user.googleId)
      } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
          res.status(400).json(e);
      }
  }
};
```

It's saying that `TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`.

fetchUserByIdFromDb:

```
const fetchUserByIdFromDb = async (Id) => {
  try {
    const [rows] = await connection.query(findUserByIdQuery, (googleId));
    console.log('orm: ', rows[0].googleId)
    return rows[0];
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error(e);
  }
};
```

How do I get the res from the controller to respond with the proper value? I'd like it to return the Id of the User, to be honest, anything from the User.

I'm using node.js and MySQL.

Comment: maybe you meant `const {googleId} = req` instead or `const googleId = req.googleId`

Answer (score 1):

LOOKS LIKE I WAS BEING SILLY!

thank you all for responding to this question, but looks like in my passport.js where I'm authenticating everything, I was using my API when I should have been using my ORM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try to log the "res" before and after fetch operation. I think that you will solve with a promise.then() block. Promise will ensure you to have the value after the fetch operation. Then you will be able to read your "user.googleId" value.

```
const promise = new Promise( (req, res) => {
    const user = res.json(await fetchUserByIdFromDb(req))
});
promise.then( (val) => res.send(user.googleId);
```

Try to implements (better than I done in my example) this type of google or just google it and try to find similar example to yours.

Comment: I logged the "res" before and after the fetch operation, and it's undefined both times.